# Why does it take so long for Postgres to return a sequence number?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have an application that does bulk loads into a large table (100 million rows). I am using Postgres' `COPY FROM` functionality to load data from a flat file. The target table has a primary key of `id`.

To get the bulk insert to work, I created the ids for each row in the load file using:

```
 SELECT  nextval('apps_id_seq'::regclass)
 FROM    "apps"
 ORDER   BY "apps"."id" ASC
 LIMIT   1
```

Unfortunately, I am no seeing this query take in excess of 150 seconds. It's causing a whole lot of backups, because some of these files have tens of thousands of rows in them.

Yet when I run that at the command line, I get the return in thousandths of a millisecond. Here is an `explain analyze`:

```
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..0.64 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using apps_pkey on apps  (cost=0.57..15886651.40 rows=228128608 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
     Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 0.030 ms
```

What could it be that causes the delay? The delay is being reported from the `NewRelic` service.

Comment: I'd say it must be locking. Nothing else makes sense. See what held strong locks on the `apps` table at that time. A manual `VACUUM FULL`, a `REINDEX`, etc.

Comment: That's definitely what it is. Somethings was doing 52K inserts per minute, so that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have studied your question hard, but can't make sense of the procedure you describe. (You might work on the description some more.)

Why would you generate sequence numbers by hand, when you can just have Postgres generate them automatically? [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html#AEN71689)

> If a list of columns is specified, `COPY` will only copy the data in the
>   specified columns to or from the file. If there are any columns in the
>   table that are not in the column list, **`COPY FROM` will insert the
>   default values for those columns**.

Bold emphasis mine. The default value for a [**`serial`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860) column is the next id from its sequence.

Are you sure you are not doing a lot of redundant work in a very expensive fashion?

Comment: The only sensible reason to do so is gapless sequences. But of course you would not then use `nextval`. BTW, 9.6 should contain a built-in gapless sequence generator so you will be able to get gapless sequences from `nextval` with all the appropriate locking.

Comment: Gapless sequences! You are a bringer of good news. :)

Comment: It's the example module for pluggable sequence access methods,  which is a feature we need for BDR global sequences too. Very good chance of getting committed in 9.6. It really should have made 9.5, pity